# Eclipse Kepler Refuses to Index files:

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am running Eclipse Kepler with the C++ toolkit. Under "Properties"->"C/C++ General"->"Paths and Symbols", I have my workspace path, the C++ standard library files, and boost. These index just fine. I have another path (call it ~/path) in the include directories, and a header file (not in the same project) included via #include . I have verified explicitly that header.hh is in ~/path/subdirectories. But still Eclipse cannot index the symbols and methods in header.hh and gives me an unresolved inclusion error.

What can be done?

Comment: Difficult to say. You said you had ~/path in the include path... and the header file in ~/path/subdirectories.... then  it should #include "subdirectories/header.hh". Other pitfall I can think of is that CDT keeps separate include paths for C++, C, and Assembler... so you might have set it in a different one... just guessing here. Does the include path show in the C++ Project explorer? Have you tried to rebuild the index?

Comment: My company's build system is set up so that we should use the #include <file.hh> syntax rather than #include "file.hh" syntax. In any case, I changed this and it still didn't index. This include path does show in the project explorer, and I have rebuilt the index many times now.

Comment: Either `#include <subdirectories/header.hh>` or `#include "subdirectories/header.hh"` the thing is that your header is not directly on the ~/path directory.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I did #include <subdirectories/header.hh> as well as #include "subdirectories/header.hh".

Comment: what about the possibility of having declared de include path only for C or asm, but not for C++?

Comment: I checked the option "Add to all configurations" and "Add to all languages". By the way, thanks for your help.